# How I trigger the "System Bell" in nodejs

Tags: javascript, unix, node.js

I'm running a long running custom nodejs script and would like to be notified when the script is completed.

How do I make nodejs trigger the "System Bell"?

Comment: The same way as with anything else you run in a console window: output the BEL character (ASCII 7) to the standard output.

Comment: Exactly what Karl says: `console.log('\u0007');`

Comment: @wulong, That worked great, thanks!  You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Output the BELL character (Unicode 0007) to the standard output.

```
console.log('\u0007');
```

**Update 2023**

Solution above doesn't work anymore, but writing directly to stdout still works (tested on Node.js v14.20):

```js
process.stdout.write('\u0007');
```

**References**

- [ASCII/ISO 8859 (Latin-1) Table](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/miles/iso8859.html)
- [Unicode Characters: 00000 to 000FF](https://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007doc/000.html)
- [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7: Portable Character Set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap06.html)
- [Programming with Unicode Documentation (unicodebook.pdf)](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/unicodebook/latest/unicodebook.pdf)
- [How a bullet turns into a beep – The Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070104-12/?p=28513)
- [Unicode 10.0.0 Final Names List](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt)

Comment: It works in terminal, but not in terminal inside vscode.

Answer (score 14):

The console.log('\u0007') didn't work for me running VSCode on windows 10.
The following code did work:

```
import { exec } from 'child_process'
exec(`rundll32 user32.dll,MessageBeep`)
```

Comment: even if the `console.log` version worked for me, it did not work after building an electron app with the code. Your solution also works for electron apps on windows 10.

Comment: one more case, use `>` redirect console output to a file

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is tagged unix, but I found it from Google so here is a Windows PowerShell solution.

The current answer works fine in Windows, but I wanted something a bit more unique than the standard Windows tone so this worked better for my needs:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

// Single beep
exec("[console]::beep(1000, 500)", {'shell':'powershell.exe'});

// Multiple beeps
exec("1..3 | %{ [console]::beep(1000, 500) }", {'shell':'powershell.exe'});
```