# Is it possible to ring the system bell with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I found the following answer, but it does not seem to work in an HTML page:

```
console.log('\u0007');
```

[How I trigger the "System Bell" in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557624/how-i-trigger-the-system-bell-in-nodejs)

Is there a way to ring the system bell from Javascript?

Chrome OSX

Comment: This answer has a function to [make a simple javascript beep()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23395136/45966)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer you linked to works for Node because Node's `console.log` writes to the [standard output](http://www.linfo.org/standard_output.html) of the process.  It's actually the system's terminal emulator that sees the `BEL` character and makes a beep.  (No different than if you put a `BEL` in a file and ran `cat` on that file.)

Since browser script does not have access to standard output, you're out of luck.

However, you could [use the `<audio>` tag to play a sound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) of your choice.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Imagine how annoying that would be... I could do this, for example:

```
console.log(new Array(100000).join('\x07'));
```

And you'd get 99999 beeps.