# Javascript How to make a noise from CLI

Tags: javascript, audio, command-line, command-line-interface, noise

I am working on a CLI app using JS, and I want it to emit a noise when I call a specific function. What should I do?

```
function emitNoise(){
//noise emitting code
}
```

Comment: I believe that there is already an answer for this here: [How I trigger the "System Bell" in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557624/how-i-trigger-the-system-bell-in-nodejs).  Also, if you want to accomplish it with a package instead, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543237/play-audio-with-node-js) seems to provide some options.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('\u0007');
```

will trigger the system bell